# Keras ImageDataGenerator for Cloud ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, gcloud

I need to train a neural net fed by some raw images that I store on the GCloud Storage. To do that I’m using the ***flow_from_directory*** method of my Keras image generator to find all the images and their related labels on the storage.

```
training_data_directory = args.train_dir
testing_data_directory = args.eval_dir

training_gen = datagenerator.flow_from_directory(
                    training_data_directory,
                    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
                    batch_size = 32)

validation_gen = basic_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                    testing_data_directory,
                    target_size = (img_width, img_height),
                    batch_size = 32)
```

My GCloud Storage architecture is the following :

**brad-bucket / data / train 

brad-bucket / data / eval**

The gsutil command allows me to be sure my folders exist.

```
brad$ gsutil ls gs://brad-bucket/data/
gs://brad-bucket/data/eval/
gs://brad-bucket/data/train/
```

So here is the script I'm running to launch the training on ML Engine with the strings I use for the paths of my directories (train_dir, eval_dir).

```
BUCKET="gs://brad-bucket"
JOB_ID="training_"$(date +%s)
JOB_DIR="gs://brad-bucket/jobs/train_keras_"$(date +%s)
TRAIN_DIR="gs://brad-bucket/data/train/"
EVAL_DIR="gs://brad-bucket/data/eval/"
CONFIG_PATH="config/config.yaml"
PACKAGE="trainer"

gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_ID \
                                    --stream-logs \
                                    --verbosity debug \
                                    --module-name trainer.task \
                                    --staging-bucket $BUCKET \
                                    --package-path $PACKAGE \
                                    --config $CONFIG_PATH \
                                    --region europe-west1 \
                                    -- \
                                    --job_dir $JOB_DIR \
                                    --train_dir $TRAIN_DIR \
                                    --eval_dir $EVAL_DIR \
                                    --dropout_one 0.2 \
                                    --dropout_two 0.2
```

Though, what I’m doing throws an OSError.

```
ERROR   2018-01-10 09:41:47 +0100   service       File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 1086, in __init__
ERROR   2018-01-10 09:41:47 +0100   service         for subdir in sorted(os.listdir(directory)):
ERROR   2018-01-10 09:41:47 +0100   service     OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://brad-bucket/data/train/'
```

When I'm using another data structure (reading the data in another way), everything is working fine, but when I'm using ***flow_from_directory*** to read from directories and subdirectories I'm always getting this same error. 
Is it possible to use this method to retrieve data from the Cloud Storage or do I have to feed the data in a different way?

Comment: hey there, it would be better if you typed or included as text the error and code snippet you included. Also if you could include what is `training_data_directory` (and testing also) would help debug this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L1196), you see that the error arises when Keras (or TF) is trying to construct the classes from your directories. Since you are giving it a GCS-directory (`gs://`), this will not work. You can bypass this error by providing the classes argument yourself, e.g. in the following way:

```
def get_classes(file_dir):
    if not file_dir.startswith("gs://"):
      classes = [c.replace('/', '') for c in os.listdir(file_dir)]
    else:
      bucket_name = file_dir.replace('gs://', '').split('/')[0]
      prefix = file_dir.replace("gs://"+bucket_name+'/', '')
      if not prefix.endswith("/"):
          prefix += "/"

      client = storage.Client()
      bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

      iterator = bucket.list_blobs(delimiter="/", prefix=prefix)
      response = iterator.get_next_page_response()
      classes = [c.replace('/','') for c in response['prefixes']]

    return classes
```

Passing these classes to `flow_from_directory` will solve your error, but it will not recognize the files itself (I now get e.g. `Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.`).

The only 'direct' workaround that I find, is to copy your files to local disk and read them from there. It would be great to have another solution (since e.g. in case of images, it can take long to copy).

Other resources also suggest to use TensorFlow's `file_io` function when interacting with GCS from Cloud ML Engine, but this will require you to fully rewrite `flow_from_directory` yourself in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I just tried the bypass and it worked perfectly. I also used Tensorflow's file_io to work with the dataset converted into a h5 file to feed the network with numpy arrays as another solution.

Comment: Did you get it to find any images with the flow_from directory? I suppose your solution replaces flow_from_directory? Can you share your code for loading and batching with TF file_io into Keras?

Comment: Yes, but according to the high number of images I had to store I chose to work with one h5 file. I posted an example of how to achieve what I did to feed the model. The only drawback I saw is that if your image dataset is quiet big (for me around 1 million 100x100x3 images ) you end up with a very big h5 file. Another solution would be to use sharded TFrecords instead.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to dumkar's solution.
One can try to work with a h5 dataset using Tensorflow's file_io.

```
with file_io.FileIO(os.path.join(data_dir, data_file_name), mode='r') as input_f:
        with file_io.FileIO('dataset.hdf5', mode='w+') as output_f:
                output_f.write(input_f.read())
dataset = h5py.File('dataset.hdf5', 'r')
```

This allows you to have a temporary local copy of a file stored in a GC bucket.
Here is a good gist by **aloisg** that demonstrates how you can create the h5 file from your image dataset : https://gist.github.com/aloisg/ac83160edf8a543b5ee6. 

You can now retrieve X_train, y_train, X_eval and y_eval from the dataset to feed the keras model easily.

Comment: can the H5 file be used as the input to flow_from_directory?

Comment: flow_from_directory looks for PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF files in subdirectories of the given directory. Though, you can use flow() to use the nparrays stored in the H5 file as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help you as your current post is. However, checking the error you get we can see it is being thrown by `os.listdir()`, so it is not a Keras problem *per se*.

This is probably due to your **directory not being absolute path or well that it does not exist (maybe a typo or similar)**. If you update your question with more information I can help you go deeper into this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! I just edited the post and I'm still working on the problem today.