# Ideal way to read data in bucket stored batches of data for Keras ML training in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-platform

This is my first attempt at training a model in the cloud and I am struggling with all the little intracacies. 
I have training data stored in a bucket within the google cloud platform,
along the lines of  `gs://test/train`
The dataset is about 100k.
Currently the data is distributed in separate folders in accordance with its labels.

I don't know the ideal way to get access to the data.
Usually in Keras I use,`ImageDataGenerator` with `flow_from_directory` and it automatically creates a generator which I can feed into my model.

Is there such as function for Python for the Google Cloud Platform?

If not what is the ideal way to access the data via generator so I can feed it to 
`Keras model.fit_generator`

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory()` currently does not allow you to stream data directly from a GCS bucket. I think you have a couple of options:

1/ Copy your data from GCS to a disk local to the VM your are using to run your script. I suppose you are doing this either via ML Engine or on a Compute Engine instance. Either way, you can copy the data at the beginning of your training script using `gsutil` or the [python cloud storage API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/). There is a downside here: this will cost you some time at the beginning of your script, especially when the dataset is large.

2/ When using `tf.keras`, you can train your model on a `tf.data` Dataset. The nice thing here is that TensorFlow's io utilities allow you to read directly from GCS buckets. If you would convert your data to TFRecords, you could instantiate a Dataset object without downloading the data to local disk first:

```
# Construct a TFRecordDataset
ds_train tf.data.TFRecordDataset('gs://') # path to TFRecords on GCS
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(1000).batch(32)

# Fit a tf.keras model
model.fit(ds_train)
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523822/best-way-to-process-terabytes-of-data-on-gcloud-ml-engine-with-keras/54523859#54523859) for more information on the TFRecord option. This works also fine with a Dataset object that is instantiated directly from images on GCS with `Dataset.from_tensor_slices`, so that you don't have to store your data in the TFRecords format first:

```
def load_and_preprocess_image(path):
"""Read an image GCS path and process it into an image tensor

Args:
    path (tensor): string tensor, pointer to GCS or local image path

Returns:
    tensor: processed image tensor
"""

    image = tf.read_file(path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    return image

image_paths = ['gs://my-bucket/img1.png',
               'gs://my-bucket/img2/png'...]
path_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_paths)
image_ds = path_ds.map(load_and_preprocess_image)
label_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels) # can be a list of labels    
model.fit(tf.data.Dataset.zip((images_ds, labels_ds)))
```

See the [tutorials on the TF website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images) for more examples.

3/ Finally, it should also be possible to write your own python generator or to adapt the source code of the `ImageDataGenerator` such that the images are read in with a TensorFlow io function. Again, these work fine with `gs://` paths:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
path = 'gs://path/to/my/image.png'
tf.image.decode_png(tf.io.read_file(path)) # this works
```

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174145/keras-imagedatagenerator-for-cloud-ml-engine/49371624#49371624). This will probably work slower than the options listed above.

Comment: For the first approach, the start of the training will be slow because as you stated we will be downloading the data to the local VM first then we start the training. But what about the other methods when we are reading data from the bucket while training, wouldn't the training be slow because we are reading data from a remote bucket?

Comment: Good question; not sure about the answer.

Comment: The tf.data pipeline is designed to handle such cases without slowdown; in this case, all you need to do is call `.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)` on your dataset. It will then download the data in parallel to the training.