# Having issues reading S3 bucket when transitioning a tensorflow model from local machine to AWS SageMaker

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

When testing on a local machine in Python I would normally use the following to read a training set with sub-directories of all the classes and files/class:

```
train_path = r"C:\temp\coins\PCGS - Gold\train"

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(100,100), classes=['0','1',2','3' etc...], batch_size=32)
```

**Found 4100 images belonging to 22 classes.**

but on AWS SageMaker's Jupyter notebook I am now pulling the files from an S3 bucket.  I tried the following:

```
bucket = "coinpath"

train_path = 's3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket, "v1")   #note that the directory structure is coinpath/v1/train where coinpath is the bucket

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(train_path, target_size=(100,100), classes=
['0','1',2','3' etc...], batch_size=32)
```

but I get: ** Found 0 images belonging to 22 classes.**

Looking for some guidance on the right way to pull training data from S3.

Comment: it seems from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736505/ideal-way-to-read-data-in-bucket-stored-batches-of-data-for-keras-ml-training-in that "ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory() currently does not allow you to stream data directly from a GCS bucket. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Ideal way to read data in bucket stored batches of data for Keras ML training in Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54736505/ideal-way-to-read-data-in-bucket-stored-batches-of-data-for-keras-ml-training-in) "ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory() currently does not allow you to stream data directly from a GCS bucket. "

I had to download the image from S3 first.  This is best for latency reasons as well.

Comment: Btw if you have many images and not sure whether you have downloaded them or not, check aws s3 sync feature.

What I usually do is !aws s3 sync s3://bucket/some_dir_prefix/ data/train